# Adding custom keys in Playwright config

Tags: key, config, playwright

I'd like to add a custom base link in my playwright config folder so that it'd be easier to maintain and reusable however I'm getting an error as it doesn't exist as a type or condition in `PlaywrighTestConfig`

The setup I got is this currently:

```
const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  testMatch: 'tests/*.ts',
  outputDir: 'tests/test-results',
  retries: 1,
  reporter: [['html', { open: 'never', outputFolder: '/test-results/html' }]],
  globalSetup: require.resolve('./tests/global-setup'),
  use: {
    headless: true,
    screenshot: 'only-on-failure',
    trace: 'retain-on-failure',
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',
    storageState: 'storageState.json'
  },
  timeout: 60000,
}
```

I'd like to add a new object variable lets call it `deleteAPIcall` so in turn make it look somewhat like this:

```
const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  testMatch: 'tests/*.ts',
  outputDir: 'tests/test-results',
  retries: 1,
  reporter: [['html', { open: 'never', outputFolder: '/test-results/html' }]],
  globalSetup: require.resolve('./tests/global-setup'),
  deleteAPIcall: 'https://delAPICall.company.com',
  use: {
    headless: true,
    screenshot: 'only-on-failure',
    trace: 'retain-on-failure',
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',
    storageState: 'storageState.json'
  },
  timeout: 60000,
}
```

I'm open to suggestions on how to add this?

Answer (score 1):

you can just add as your way, and then you can get the value from testInfo as following:

```
const endpoint = testInfo.config.projects[0].use.deleteAPIcall
```

Comment: Do you mean that if we put that in the `use` section of the project we can just put any arbitrary property there?

Comment: in my view, yes. I use this method and get what i  want.